# Where are the APIs ? [Galaxy S7]

Tags: android

The S7 got a whole lot of new functions. Heart Rate Monitor, Always-On-Screen, where can I find worthful references or informtation about the API to be used to use these features?

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/home.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heart Rate Monitor functions can be found in the [Sensor Extension SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#sensor-extension). I think the Always On mode is only available for selected Samsung apps. It cannot be used by third-party apps.